# For a simple key-value pair list JSON, use jq to print the sum of values by range

Tags: jq

Consider the following JSON having a list of key-value pairs

```
{
  "session1": 128,
  "session2": 1048596,
  "session3": 3145728,
  "session4": 3145828,
  "session5": 11534338,
  "session6": 11544336,
  "session7": 2097252
}
```

The value is number of bytes

I want to print sum of values by range - the ranges being (lower bound included, high bound excluded); 0-1MB, 1-2MB, 2-3MB, ... 12-13MB.

```
 1MB =  1048576
 2MB =  2097152
 3MB =  3145728
 4MB =  4194304
 5MB =  5242880
 6MB =  6291456
 7MB =  7340032
 8MB =  8388608
 9MB =  9437184
10MB = 10485760
11MB = 11534336
12MB = 12582912
13MB = 13631488
```

The expected output is

```
{
  "0-1MB": 128,
  "1-2MB": 1048596,
  "2-3MB": 2097252,
  "3-4MB": 6291556,
  "11-12MB": 23078674
}
```

The above is just representative, suggestions are welcome (*like having the value output in human readable format*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In analogy to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76797849/2158479), iterate over the values before dividing, and add them instead of `1`:

```bash
reduce (map(.) | sort[]) as $n ({}; .[$n / 1048576 | floor | "\(.)-\(.+1)MB"] += $n)
```

```json
{
  "0-1MB": 128,
  "1-2MB": 1048596,
  "2-3MB": 2097252,
  "3-4MB": 6291556,
  "11-12MB": 23078674
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/H_8fzKrz6WH)

Comment: Thanks @pmf. This gives me what I was after. The only change I had to make was add `+1`


`reduce (map(.) | sort[]) as $n ({}; .[$n / 1048576 | floor | "\(.)-\(.+1)MB"] += $n)`

Comment: @JojoThomas Good spotting! This must have slipped through when simplifying the code. I am going to correct it in the answer.